# Evaluating the real part of an expression

Tags: complex

I want to get the Real part of this expression - shouldn't be too hard to evaluate. Why is Mathematica not evaluating but returning the same code?

```
In == Re[χ/(1 + I ω τ)]
Out == Re[χ/(1 + I ω τ)]
```

Thank you!

Comment: To directly answer the question as asked: *Mathematica* has no way of knowing that you intend the symbolic entities $\chi$, $\omega$, and $\tau$ to be real; without further information, such entities might be complex.

Comment: Same as this [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65381/how-do-i-declare-that-a-variable-represents-a-real-number/65383#65383)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [Re](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html), under Possible Issues

Re can stay unevaluated for numeric arguments:
`{Re[Log[2 + I]], Re[Sqrt[1 + I]]}`

To get around this, try using `Re[ComplexExpand[χ/(1 + I ω τ)]]`.

Comment: To go one step further, you can display the real part by assuming the variables are real (just like `ComplexExpand` did): `Refine[Re[ComplexExpand[\[Chi]/(1+I \[Omega] \[Tau])]],{\[Chi],\[Omega],\[Tau]}\[Element]Reals]`

Comment: Sorry,  I accidentally downvoted and didn't notice fast enough.  Reversed :-)